# Dice Rolling Simulator

Tags: python-3.x, simulator, dice

I am making a Dice rolling simulator in python to play dnd. I am very new to python so please don't make fun of me if my code is really bad.

```
import random
while 1 == 1:
    dice = input("What kind of dice would you like to roll?: ") # This is asking what kind of dice to roll (d20, d12, d10, etc.)
    number = int(input("How many times?: ")) # This is the number of times that the program will roll the dice
    if dice == 'd20':
        print(random.randint(1,21) * number)
    elif dice == 'd12':
        print(random.randint(1,13) * number)
    elif dice == 'd10':
        print(random.randint(1,11) * number)
    elif dice == 'd8':
        print(random.randint(1,9) * number)
    elif dice == 'd6':
        print(random.randint(1,7) * number)
    elif dice == 'd4':
        print(random.randint(1,5) * number)
    elif dice == 'd100':
        print(random.randint(1,101) * number)
    elif dice == 'help':
        print("d100, d20, d12, d10, d8, d6, d4, help, quit")
    elif dice == 'quit':
        break
    else:
        print("That's not an option. Type help to get a list of different commands.")

quit()
```

My original attention was just to let it be and not make a number variable, but then my brother reminded me that some weapons have multiple rolls and instead of just rolling more than once, I want to have an input asking how many times to roll the dice. The problem with my code right now is that it will randomize the number and **then** times it by two. What I want it to do is times the number of **different** integers and add them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use a `for`-loop and iterate over the `number` of times the user wants to roll the dice, while saving those to a list to display each roll of the die.

For example, the first die may look like this:

```
rolls = []
if dice == 'd20':
    for roll in range(number):
        rolls.append(random.randint(1,21))
    print('rolls: ', ', '.join([str(roll) for roll in rolls]))
    print('total:', sum(rolls))
```

Example output:

```
What kind of dice would you like to roll?: d20
How many times?: 2
rolls:  10, 15
total: 25
```

Comment: Thanks man, I appreciate it. I am new to python and i have trouble sometimes wrapping my head around it sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

print("Rolling the Dice....")
dice_number = random.randint(1, 6)
print(dice_number)
limit = 0
while limit <= 4:

    ask = input("Would you like to roll again?? Yes or No ").upper()
    limit = limit + 1
    if ask == "YES":
        print(random.randint(1, 6))
    elif ask == "NO":
        print("Thank You.")
        break
    else:
        print("Thank You.")
        break
 else:
    print("Limit Reached..TRY AGAIN!!")
```